How to wire a quad op amp for single supply operation
I want to use a quad opamp instead of four single channels. The datasheet specifies that single supply operation is possible, but does not specify the circuit. Can anyone tell me the correct way to do this?
The circuit I'm building is a Linkwitz–Riley filter, and the opamp is an OPA1664, if that makes a difference.
Any help is appreciated.

It's possible, but kind of depends on the specifics of what you're trying to do.  You have to bias the inputs to stay within the common-mode range, and you have to be OK with where the output voltage "zero" is and what the output voltage swing is.  Creating an artificial "ground" at half the supply voltage is one method.  Can you give us a little more detail on what you're trying to do? Inverting amp? Non-inverting? What are you driving? Is AC coupling acceptable, or do you need response down to DC?

A schematic of your as-is circuit would be helpful.

You may find it easier and better to create a negative rail compared to biasing all the op-amps at mid-rail and dealing with any resulting audio turn-on thump or whatever. Just sayin'.

It doesn't matter if you use a quad or four single op amps. What you need to do to make them work with a single supply depends on the actual filter circuit which you have not shown.

Input signal voltage range?  Output signal voltage range?  Cutoff frequency / filter bandwidth?  S.c.h.e.m.a.t.i.c - ?  All of these things matter because of passive component connections to GND.

I can't directly address your own application without more information, but I can provide "any help". You seem to be confused about dual supplies vs. single-ended ones, so I will address only that.
It's a common misconception that a single ended supply is somehow different from a dual one, where op-amps are concerned. A typical op-amp doesn't concern itself with where "zero volts" is, all it knows is the potential difference between its own two supply pins.
For instance, if you connect an op-amp's negative supply pin to +4V, and its positive supply pin to +14V, from the op-amp's perspective you have given it a single \$(+14V)-(+4V)=10V\$ supply. Its output may swing only between those extremes of +4V and +14V, and its inputs must also always fall within this range. This situation is shown below left:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
On the right, I have changed things to have the op-amp powered from ±5V, but it has no idea that anything changed. As far as its concerned it still has a single 10V supply.
The only real difference between those two circuits is what I (the designer) have decided to call "ground", which is the node that I arbitrarily declare to have 0V potential. You'll notice that the op-amp doesn't have any pins called "ground", or "GND", and has no connection to that node. Therefore it has no concept of ground, or where "zero volts" is. It knows only the maximum and minimum potentials that its inputs and outputs may have.
This supply agnosticism is really clear for the voltage follower:

simulate this circuit
The op-amp here can't possibly know anything about ground, because it has no connection to it, and yet it is quite able to "follow" the input, producing output \$V_{OUT}\$ (orange) equal in potential to input \$V_{IN}\$ (blue):

The supply potentials of +4V and +14V are constraints for the op-amp output, causing it to "clip" when the input strays outside that range, as is clearly shown above. In fact this circuit would no doubt damage the op-amp because the non-inverting input swings well outside those bounds.
I hope it's obvious why the following circuit cannot possibly work:

simulate this circuit
In this non-inverting amplifier configuration, we would expect gain to be \$1+\frac{R_1}{R_2}=2\$. The op-amp is given 0V and +12V supplies, and therefore it cannot output negative potentials. If \$V_{IN}\$ swings above and below zero, then there will be clipping:

There are two solutions. Arguably the easiest is to provide the op-amp with a "dual" supply, extending above and below ground, so that the output and inputs can have negative potentials:

simulate this circuit

The second is to "bias" all the signals to be centered not at zero volts, but somewhere between the supply bounds. Here I provide the op-amp with a single-ended 12V supply, but I use a potential divider R3,R4 to bias the input half-way at +6V. Capacitors C1 and C2 decouple DC from the signals everywhere (AC coupling), allowing potentials to have average values at +6V:

simulate this circuit

Notice how even though he input \$V_{IN}\$ oscillates around 0V (going both positive and negative), the output is centered around +6V.
The op-amp's output is still constrained to lie within its supplies of 0V and +12V, and will exhibit clipping if the input signal is too large:

So, it's either a dual supply, where all signals can be centered on 0V, or biasing of signals to all be mid-way between the bounds of a single supply. Those are your options.
Regarding the use of four op-amps in a single package (like the OPA1664), as opposed to four individually packaged op-amps, the only difference is that the quad-package forces you to provide all the op-amps with the same supply potentials. Consequently every op-amp in the IC will have the same input and output bounds. By contrast, individually packaged op-amps such as the OPA377 can all be powered from different, independent supplies, and are thus able to deal with signals having different minimum/maximum potential.
Lastly, don't let the datasheets fool you into believing that an op-amp must have single or dual supplies. The reason that an op-amp might be called "single-supply" is more to do with its ability to handle input signals (and produce an output signal) with potentials down to the negative supply.
An op-amp that can do that is generally called a "single-supply" device. An example is the famous LM358, which can handle inputs even slightly lower than the potential of its negative supply pin. It will not, however, work well if either input gets within a volt or so of the positive supply, which is often overlooked by newcomers to electronics. Similarly, it can produce outputs very close to its negative supply, but cannot get its output closer than a volt or so from its positive supply potential. Its effective "operating range" is at the bottom of the supply bounds, and since that's often 0V, such devices are associated with single-ended supplies.
This does not mean that you cannot use an LM358 with a dual supply, of say −5V and +5V. You can, and it would work perfectly well in that configuration.
Compare that to the TL081, which won't work properly with inputs closer than 1.5V to either supply potential, or produce an output approaching within 1.5V of either extreme. This behavioural quirk makes it unsuitable for use in applications where signals are near zero volts, and the negative supply is also 0V. For this reason, in its datasheet you find that all references to its supply are quoted "±something", and it's generally referred to as a "dual supply" device. However, you can of course use the TL081 with a single supply (say 0V and +12V), it's just that all its signals will have to be biased (centered) well above 0V, and well below +12V.
The OPA1664 datasheet states clearly "These devices operate over a very wide supply range of ±1.5 V to ±18 V, or +3 V to +36 V". That's implying either dual or single supply operation, but as I explained above, we knew that anyway. All op-amps can work with single or dual supplies, it's just that some work better than others with signals at the lower end of the supply bounds.
